# Is it possible to run ROS2 via wireguard

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I like to connect ROS2 nodes via a wireguard vpn network. Is this possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413513/is-it-possible-to-run-ros2-via-wireguard/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on ROS Answers with karma: 847 on 2023-03-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got it working and prepared an example on [github](https://github.com/tuw-robotics/ros2_cyclonedds_wireguard)

Using Eclipse Cyclone DDS, but one has to set some variables

```
export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_cyclonedds_cpp
export CYCLONEDDS_URI=file:///$(pwd)/cyclonedds.xml
```

and the cyclonedds.xml  looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CycloneDDS xmlns="https://cdds.io/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://cdds.io/config https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds/master/etc/cyclonedds.xsd">
    <Domain id="any">
        <General>
            <Interfaces>
                <NetworkInterface name="wg0"/>
            </Interfaces>
        </General>
        <Discovery>
            <Peers>
            <Peer address="192.168.33.80"/>
            <Peer address="192.168.33.51"/>
            </Peers>
            <ParticipantIndex>auto</ParticipantIndex>
        </Discovery>
    </Domain>
</CycloneDDS>
```

---

Originally posted by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) with karma: 847 on 2023-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2